# Why is focusing an html element with the keyboard different than focusing with the mouse?

Tags: html, css, focus

I'm trying to style an element based on whenever it's focused (either by holding a mouseclick on it, or while selecting it using the tab key), but I'm having different behaviors depending on which method I'm using.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.v-expansion-panel-header:focus {
    outline: 2px solid;
    outline-color: blue;
    background-color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <v-expansion-panels variant="accordion" flat>
        <v-expansion-panel>
            <div class="header">
                <v-expansion-panel-header flat>
                    Accordion
                </v-expansion-panel-header>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <v-expansion-panel-content>
                    <slot></slot>
                </v-expansion-panel-content>
            </div>
        </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
</div>
```

My element:
[image]

Here is what it looks like when I focus with the tab key:
[image]

and here when I hold a mouse click on it:

[image]

What explains this behavior?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML. And what do you find is the CSS which is being applied (E.g. styling from the browser)?

Comment: When you say “hold a mouse click”, I’m not sure what you mean. Please clarify whether you are talking about **hovering** the mouse or **clicking** the mouse.

Comment: @AHaworth added HTML

Comment: @BrettDonald I'm not talking about hovering, I'm talking about physically doing a mouse click without releasing it over the element

Comment: It might help us give a proper explanation if we saw the resultant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When using the tab key to focus on elements, the :focus pseudo-class is usually activated. However, when you click on an element with a mouse, the :focus state might not be activated, especially for elements that are not interactive by default.

To avoid that, you can use :focus for keyboard focusing and :focus-within for both keyboard and mouse focusing. That makes sure the styles are applied when the element/any of its descendants are focused on. You can also use JS event listeners to detect keyboard and mouse focuses, and then use event handlers to work with the styles. That gives you more control.

For the CSS solution, though, you can use something like this:

```
.v-expansion-panel-header:focus,
.v-expansion-panel-header:focus-within {
    outline: 2px solid blue;
    background-color: white;
}
```

(I went ahead and put the outline attributes together for you!)

Comment: Hello, I tried this and I think it worked. The element is not completely white as I wanted, but it's lighter than before. At the end of the day, what I'm trying to achieve is to get rid of the brightness dimming down when I focus on the element with tab, which I thought would be by changing the background color. Do you know what's the css property that takes care of it? I've already tried playing with `filter: brightness()`

Comment: I'd need your code to figure that out, can you share that?